# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[108.62257164103005]'

Tags: python, list, error-handling, goto, python-turtle

I am trying to convert a list to a float so have first converted it into a string but when I try to convert the string into a float it doesn't work and gives me the error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[108.62257164103005]'
Sorry if I am being a noob, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your code? The reason it's not working is because of the brackets around the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what the brackets are for, but you can convert `string` to `float` like this:

```
str1 = '108.62257164103005'
str2 = float(str1)

print(type(str2))
print(str2)
```

Gives you:

```
<class 'float'>
108.62257164103005
```

Or if you want to go from `list` to `float`, just iterate over it

```
str0 = ['108.62257164103005']
for i in str0:
    print(float(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got brackets in your string.

You can run something like this first to clean your string up:
`string.replace(']','').replace('[','')`
or
`string[1:-1]` which will remove the first and last characters